# Sliding functionality with circles effect

Tags: android, user-interface

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tapsi.android.passenger&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwyLDEsImNvbS50YXBzaS5hbmRyb2lkLnBhc3NlbmdlciJd

(first image from the left guide screen)

Hello Please guide me how can i achieve above sliding functionality using android sdk.
Like when i slide small circles change accordingly.
 Any help tutorials links are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make them with the SupportLib `ViewPager` and this open source library: [ViewPagerIndicator](http://viewpagerindicator.com/)